# Output while input is being typed

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a way in c++ to display code compiled under a box to read information, so if it were a scoreboard there would be the actual scoreboard under something to read the info, something that would look like:

> Enter Score:
>
> Score:

So the `Enter Score` would be there while the `score` is displayed and the score is changed when something new is typed in the `Enter score`

Comment: Not in standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this that is built into C++, but you can use a library for this. One such library is ncurses, and I have heard good things about GNU readline as well.